# how to use post thumbnail url in background image in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, background-image, thumbnails

I'm using this code.

```
<div class="bg-img1 size-a-3 how1 pos-relative" style="background-image: url();">
```

At this time how to get the post thumbnail url in background image?

Answer (score 4):

The code should be like following,

```
<div class="bg-img1 size-a-3 how1 pos-relative" style="background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>);">
```

And if you want to get post thumbnail from a specific post/page using post ID it will be like following,

```
<div class="bg-img1 size-a-3 how1 pos-relative" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id); ?>);">
```